# How to select a single row, where multiple rows match join criteria?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

In the table, EVENTDATA (see below), I would like to select a single row per day for each user.

For example:

| name | eventDate | eventName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 2022-1-21 | car |
| User1 | 2022-1-21 | bus |
| User1 | 2022-1-23 | bus |
| User1 | 2022-1-23 | horse |

The result set should only include a single row for each day.

| name | eventDate | eventName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 2022-1-21 | bus |
| User1 | 2022-1-23 | bus |

```
// Test query
// EVENTDATA: This table holds the name of the event in addtion to the user name and date.  We only need one row for each unique date for each user.
let EVENTDATA = datatable(name:string, eventDate:datetime, eventName: string)
[
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-12), 'Mets',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-12), 'Dentist',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-12), 'Movie',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-13), 'Mets',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-13), 'Movie',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-14), 'Anything',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-14), 'Else',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-14), 'Movie',  
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-15), 'Mets',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-15), 'Dentist',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-15), 'Movie',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-18), 'Thing1',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-18), 'Thing2',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-18), 'Cats',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-22), 'Play',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-25), 'Darts',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-30), 'Make',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-30), 'Samples',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-30), 'Shorter',
    'Mary', datetime(2022-01-17), 'Cricket',
    'Mary', datetime(2022-01-20), 'Football',
    'Mary', datetime(2022-01-20), 'Rugby',
    'Mary', datetime(2022-01-22), 'Curling' 
];
```

Comment: Just an arbitrary event? How does that make sense business wise?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz
Yes.  All we need to know is that the user "touched" the database on a particular day.   We don't care what exactly what they did.

Comment: At first, I thought using "kind=innerunique" would help, but over a 90 day period, for instance, a user may perform an action many different days and "innerunique" would de-duplicate the data and leave me with only a single action.

Comment: If we don't care about the details of the event, why do we need EVENTDATA  in the first place? Isn't EVENTDATE enough?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz
I suppose my example was not a good one.   The data is coming from App Insights.
A user will perform many actions in a day.   We only need to know about one of them for that day.

We want to know If the user performed an action on the database.   We don't care how often, or what exactly was done.  We just need to know that on such and such a date, they accessed the database.  <br />
So, if they performed 3 actions on the 12th, 4 on the 13th, and 1 on the 15th; I only want to know that on each of those days it was touched at least once; How often, is not of concern

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz 
I've updated my question.  I've removed the EVENTDATE datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/distinctoperator) operator

```
let EVENTDATA = datatable(name:string, eventDate:datetime, eventName: string)
[
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-12), 'Mets',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-12), 'Dentist',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-12), 'Movie',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-13), 'Mets',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-13), 'Movie',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-14), 'Anything',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-14), 'Else',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-14), 'Movie',  
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-15), 'Mets',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-15), 'Dentist',
    'Jack', datetime(2022-01-15), 'Movie',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-18), 'Thing1',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-18), 'Thing2',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-18), 'Cats',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-22), 'Play',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-25), 'Darts',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-30), 'Make',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-30), 'Samples',
    'Jill', datetime(2022-01-30), 'Shorter',
    'Mary', datetime(2022-01-17), 'Cricket',
    'Mary', datetime(2022-01-20), 'Football',
    'Mary', datetime(2022-01-20), 'Rugby',
    'Mary', datetime(2022-01-22), 'Curling' 
];
EVENTDATA
| distinct name, eventDate
```

| name | eventDate |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | 2022-01-12T00:00:00Z |
| Jack | 2022-01-13T00:00:00Z |
| Jack | 2022-01-14T00:00:00Z |
| Jack | 2022-01-15T00:00:00Z |
| Mary | 2022-01-17T00:00:00Z |
| Jill | 2022-01-18T00:00:00Z |
| Mary | 2022-01-20T00:00:00Z |
| Jill | 2022-01-22T00:00:00Z |
| Mary | 2022-01-22T00:00:00Z |
| Jill | 2022-01-25T00:00:00Z |
| Jill | 2022-01-30T00:00:00Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5XUQWuDMBQH8Lvgd8jNFixonGx07CDVHQaWsUovY4doH20w6oivBWEffol2pQeHMbmFHy/Jn8cTgCTZJ9ssjrKIvJADQ7VzAYuaVbBuUfL66BK4QI0xQ1grAMgruJ5ttSIDW9rWp20RtZw3VpSOS/7wgnqUrjx/5dOlS5wUsHVcIxqrO3iLhjptLhymbWD%20iGBG2Qdto7rDkwrDkCeiNa18fQUhUzo0/144K%20NwJAwuxKh90jbTSfhzMDXEG3b/vX8o7ZviXbBumg5JMGlQNvD6HFg5HcNAd6z6FmBaeHdqJIK86ZTJbjSIxz4IyYsScFLTvvZr02DO9O1G/ON8zLtp28e8OUuh%2016159ezbd2Gim39kINqL14XSPRQuZsmv6etCq1%20BAAA)

Comment: Ha!!  I was just about to post this very same result!!!  I was going over your answers to some similar questions, and learned quite a bit.   It inspired me to look closer at summarize.
Thank you.

Comment: The requirement was updated.  Now, I need to return the entire row that has been selected.   The following query I found does the trick.  Again, inspired by your articles. EVENTDATA | summarize take_any(*) by eventDate, name

Comment: It's great to see you making progress. In SO we don't modify answered question.  Please post a new question of needed